# jquery - get next level children only

Tags: javascript, jquery

for example:

```
<div id="headerWrapper">
                <H1>TEST</H1>
                <div id="paarofileLinks">
                    <ul id="primaryNav" role="navigation">
                        <li id="musicNav" class="navItem">
                            <a href="/music" class="nav-link">Music</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="listenNav" class="navItem">
                            <a href="/listen" class="nav-link">Radio</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="eventsNav" class="navItem">
                            <a href="/events" class="nav-link nna" id="vbulletin_css2">Events</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="chartsNav" class="navItem">
                            <a href="/charts" class="nav-link">Charts</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="communityNav" class="navItem">
                            <a href="/community" class="nav-link">Community</a>
                        </li>
                        <li id="originalsNav" class="navItem">
                            <div>
                                <a href="http://originals.last.fm" class="nav-link">Originals</a>
                            </div>

                        </li>
                    </ul>
                </div>
```

if i used this selector

```
$("#headerWrapper").children("*");
```

it will get all the children but i need to return just

```
<H1>TEST</H1> 
<div id="paarofileLinks"></div>
```

without `<ul>` and the remained list

note: i don't know the structure of the page so i need something to be general and work with all structures

Comment: What you've described **is** the functionality of the `.children()` function, though you don't need to use the `"*"` selector.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unlike [`find()`](http://api.jquery.com/find/), [`children()`](http://api.jquery.com/children/) only returns the *direct* children of a given element.

So your query *should* do exactly what you want and only return the two elements in question. If that's not the case, there is something else going wrong. See the example code snippet using pretty much your exact code, giving the correct result:

```js
$("#headerWrapper").children().each(function(){console.log(this)});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="headerWrapper">
  <H1>TEST</H1>
  <div id="paarofileLinks">
    <ul id="primaryNav" role="navigation">
      <li id="musicNav" class="navItem">
        <a href="/music" class="nav-link">Music</a>
      </li>
      <li id="listenNav" class="navItem">
        <a href="/listen" class="nav-link">Radio</a>
      </li>
      <li id="eventsNav" class="navItem">
        <a href="/events" class="nav-link nna" id="vbulletin_css2">Events</a>
      </li>
      <li id="chartsNav" class="navItem">
        <a href="/charts" class="nav-link">Charts</a>
      </li>
      <li id="communityNav" class="navItem">
        <a href="/community" class="nav-link">Community</a>
      </li>
      <li id="originalsNav" class="navItem">
        <div>
          <a href="http://originals.last.fm" class="nav-link">Originals</a>
        </div>

      </li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</div>
```

Side note: The selector you use is not necessary, because `children()` and `children("*")` are semantically equivalent.

Comment: i'm using [phpquery](http://code.google.com/p/phpquery/) and it's seems a bug in the library that get all children thanks for your answer